# Is there any hope to significantly simplify this function (make it shortened) for general $\delta$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I have a long function which is a sum of exponential terms $Exp\left({\frac{2\,n\, i\, \pi   }{11}}\,\delta\right)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\delta=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$. Is there any hope to significantly simplify this function (make it shortened) for general $\delta\,$? Something like expressing exponential terms in terms of each other, say in terms of $Exp\left({\frac{2\, i\, \pi   }{11}}\,\delta\right)$ or ...?

$$ 2 e^{\frac{2 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+5 e^{\frac{4 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+8 e^{\frac{6 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+14 e^{\frac{8 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+20 e^{\frac{10 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+30 e^{\frac{12 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+22 e^{\frac{18 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+17 e^{\frac{20 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+6 e^{\frac{24 i \pi  \delta }{11}}-2 e^{\frac{26 i \pi  \delta }{11}}-8 e^{\frac{28 i \pi  \delta }{11}}-20 e^{\frac{30 i \pi  \delta }{11}}-31 e^{\frac{32 i \pi  \delta }{11}}-60 e^{\frac{34 i \pi  \delta }{11}}-31 e^{\frac{40 i \pi  \delta }{11}}-20 e^{\frac{42 i \pi  \delta }{11}}-2 e^{\frac{46 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+6 e^{\frac{48 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+10 e^{\frac{50 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+17 e^{\frac{52 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+22 e^{\frac{54 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+30 e^{\frac{56 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+20 e^{\frac{62 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+14 e^{\frac{64 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+5 e^{\frac{68 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+2 e^{\frac{70 i \pi  \delta }{11}}+e^{\frac{72 i \pi  \delta }{11}}  $$

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can write
$$\exp\frac{4\pi i\delta}{11}=\left(\exp\frac{2\pi i\delta}{11}\right)^2,$$
and more generally
$$\exp\frac{2\pi i\delta n}{11}=\left(\exp\frac{2\pi i\delta}{11}\right)^n$$
for any integer $n$. So if you set $u=\exp2\pi i\delta/11$, you can rewrite your function as a polynomial in $u$:
$$2u+5u^2+8u^3+14u^4+20u^5+30u^6+22u^9+17u^{10}+6u^{12}-2u^{13}$$
$$-8u^{14}-20u^{15}-31u^{16}-60u^{17}-31u^{20}-20u^{21}-2u^{23}+6u^{24}+10u^{25}$$
$$+17u^{26}+22u^{27}+30u^{28}+20u^{31}+14u^{32}+5u^{34}+2u^{35}+u^{36}.$$

Comment: +1 And you can speed up the computations of the powers of $u$ by reusing them to find new ones: for example $u^5 = u^2u^3$. . Check out Horner's method for polynomials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method

Comment: Thanks. But I meant to make the function length shorter; the comment by Ethan Bolker sounds helpful.

Comment: you can also factorize, Wolfram Alpha yields $u (2 + u (5 + u (8 + u (14 + u (20 + 30 u + 22 u^4 + 17 u^5 + 6 u^7] - 2 u^8)))))$